# Retrieve the call SID on the Twilio Android client

Tags: android, twilio

I'm using the Twilio Android client to initiate a call and I require the SID for the currently connected call. I've set up a `ConnectionListener` whose `onConnected` callback is properly invoked and receives an instance of `Connection`. However the call SID (identified by the key "CallSid") seems to be absent in the parameters map of the `Connection` object.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Connection connection) {

    String sid = connection.getParameters()
        .get(Connection.IncomingParameterCallSIDKey); //sid is null

    ...
}
```

Is there an alternate method which can be used to retrieve the call SID?

Comment: I got it using same method...

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to get the latest Call SID.

check out this link .. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call
create a php webservice and get the SID of the latest call that you have made. Let me know if this works!